# Data Manipulation Python -Iterating rows

Tags: python, pandas

This is my data:

```
S.No StartMilepost  End Milepost  Segment Length  
1     0.01           0.03          0.02
```

I want an ouput like this:

```
S.No StartMilepost  End Milepost  Segment Length  
1     0.01           0.02          0.01
2     0.02           0.03          0.01
```

I have tried this code:

```
split_rows = (df2['SegmentLength'] / 0.01)  

while split_rows.any():
    df2.loc[split_rows,'StartMilepost']=df2.loc[split_rows, 'StartMilepost']

    #update the end Milepost of old rows
    df2.loc[split_rows, 'EndMilepost'] = df2.loc[split_rows, 'StartMilepost'] 
          +0.01

     #update the duration of all rows
    df2['SegmentLength'] = df2['EndMilepost'] - df2['StartMilepost']

    #when job is done:

df2.sort_index().reset_index(drop=True)
df2 = df2.append(new_rows)
```

Comment: I would love to see what other solutions are there. I was thinking of iterating over rows and create list of numpy array inside the loop using numpy.arange and combining them at the end
`dfcheck =pd.DataFrame({'start': [0.2, 0.5], 'end': [0.5, 0.9], 'segment': [0.3, 0.4]})`
`for ii, jj in dfcheck.iterrows():`
`(np.arange(jj['start'], jj['end'], 0.1), np.arange(jj['start']+.1, jj['end']+.1, 0.1)`

Comment: As it stands, your question is not clear about the rules for generating your output. Though we could infer for your single row presented here, how you want to extend to more complex data is not clear. Please update your question with details about the process of generating output from input.

Comment: S.No StartMilepost  End Milepost  Segment Length  
1                  0.01           0.03          0.02  (difference between Start and End Milepost)       
I want an ouput like this:

S.No StartMilepost  End Milepost  Segment Length  
1     0.01           0.02          0.01
2     0.02           0.03          0.01(This has been broken into rows of 0.01 segment length ).